# any to-many to-many predicate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I can get a predicate like

```
ANY alpha.prop LIKE $SEARCH_TERM
```

to work where ***alpha*** is a to-many relationship, but how do I get

```
ANY alpha.beta.prop LIKE $SEARCH_TERM
```

to work where ***alpha*** is a to-many relationship and ***beta*** is a to-many relationship on ***alpha***, this throws the exception '*multiple to-many keys not allowed here*'.

Comment: Did you set inversion for this relationship in Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the way to do this is to do the search on bottom child element instead so the query string becomes

```
prop LIKE $SEARCH_TERM
```

and then enumerate through the result and grab the parent of the parent and stick them in a set to remove duplicates, like

```
NSMutableSet  * mySet = [NSMutableSet set];
for( MyChild * c in [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:theFetchRequest error:&theError] )
{
    [mySet addObject:c.parent.parent];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps. Let's assume that `b` is a one-to-many relationship from `A` to `B`  and `c` is a one-to-many relationship from  `B` to `C`, then you could first fetch all `B` objects that are related to any `C` object with the desired property:

```
NSFetchRequest *request1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"B"];
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY(c.prop) LIKE %@", searchTerm];
request1.predicate = predicate1;
NSArray *bList = [context executeFetchRequest:request1 error:NULL];
```

Then fetch all `A` objects that are related to any `B` object from the intermediate result:

```
NSFetchRequest *request2 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"A"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY(b) IN %@", bList];
request2.predicate = predicate2;

NSArray *aList = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:NULL];
```